# Remove Server Header from TemplateResponse Django 3.1?? (header not showing)

Tags: python, django, backend

So I have to remove or hide the server header from a django app I am working on for security (I was asked to remove it). I tried removing it from a middleware but the header is not showing! Nonetheless it is shown when the page loads.

I tried this, but it raises a ValueError "too many values to unpack"

```
class NoServerHeaderMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response._headers['Server'] = "Empty"
        return response
```

When I explore the response this is all there is:

```
{'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), 'content-length': ('Content-Length', '26292'), 'x-frame-options': ('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN'), 'vary': ('Vary', 'Cookie'), 'x-content-type-options': ('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff'), 'referrer-policy': ('Referrer-Policy', 'same-origin')}
```

So, not being Server header in there I can not really modify it can I? What am I missing? Where could the header be being added?